# CPU/GPU fan not working properly on Intel Macbook 4,1 under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: macbook, mac, cpu, fan, temperature

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Intel MacBook 4,1 and I have noticed that the cpu temperature is getting very high and the fan, although working, is not increasing its speed to cope with the increased temperature as it did under Mac OSX...

This is the first time I've run Ubuntu on an Apple machine so I'm not familiar with the compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `macfanctld` from the MacTel PPA: https://launchpad.net/macfanctld

Download link: https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2028802/+listing-archive-extra

Do it quickly, before your computer blows up.

Comment: Sounds like apple didn't properly follow the ACPI standard.

Comment: Why would they? They're _Apple_. I'm on a MBP and I bought it specifically for running Linux, but I knew I was getting myself into some real "fun."